# Get underlying image name for Google Cloud Launcher deployment

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'd like to deploy MongoDB in Google Cloud Compute Engine using `terraform`. Since this is an experimental setup, I'd like to use some pre-configured image to save time. Browsing through Google Cloud Launcher I've found this [MongoDB deployments](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/browse?q=mongo&filter=solution-type:vm&filter=category:database).

After some more Googling I've found [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/mongodb-cloud-manager/blob/master/mongodb-instance-template.jinja#L34) Google Deployment Manager example, where I found project name for Cloud Launcher images: `click-to-deploy`.

Using it I've managed to list all MongoDB `click-to-deploy` images:

```
gcloud compute images list --project click-to-deploy-images --regexp mongodb.+ --uri
```

Which gave me this list:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/mongodb-3-2-debian-8-jessie-20161006-083532
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/mongodb-3-2-debian-8-jessie-20161111-154124
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/mongodb-3-4-debian-8-jessie-20170117-113500
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/mongodb-3-4-debian-8-jessie-20170119-150929
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/mongodb-32-1607281513-debian-8-jessie-v20160718
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/mongodb-cloud-manager-bootstrap-ubuntu-v20160516a
```

But there is no way to correlate these images to Cloud Launcher deployments. I've thought about using image/deployment timestamps  for this, but unfortunately they don't match.

So, the question is, how to get underlying image for Google Cloud Launcher deployment?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer I was hoping for, but it's the best I've got for now.

You have to deploy VM using Google Cloud Launcher and grab image name afterwards from Google Deployment Manager. To do so, you have to expand `Template details` and click on template type (`mongodb.jinja` in my case).

It's also gives you a complete Deployment Manager config (with metadata, scripts and other stuff).

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Google Deployment Manager]